# downloadProgress not emitted from QNetworkReply

Tags: qt, qt4, qtnetwork

I'm trying to build a module which downloads a binary file in Qt, using `QNetworkAccessManager`. I use the same approach detailed in the documentation (see below), but while I do get `readyRead` signals, `downloadProgress` never arrives.

Everything happens on the same thread (the project is big so I cannot paste it all).

Any ideas?

```
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl("http://XXX.s3.amazonaws.com/XXX.exe");
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "MyOwnBrowser 1.0");

QNetworkAccessManager * m_manager = new QNetworkAccessManager( this );
m_reply = m_manager->get(request);
m_reply->setParent(this);

connect(m_reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(slotReadyRead()));
connect(m_reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal)),
this, SLOT(replyDownloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal)));
```

Comment: Do you actyally read stuff on readyRead? Nothing in posted code does any downloading...

Comment: yes actually i do read, just didnt paste it here. used browser sample from qt code

Answer (score 2):

ok found it
wow what a simple mistake.

the answer is syntactic:

```
connect(m_reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal)),
        this, SLOT(replyDownloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal)));
```

is an error

it should be:

```
connect(m_reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64 , qint64 )),
        this, SLOT(replyDownloadProgress(qint64 , qint64 ));
```

once i changed it, i got the signal.

QT DOES NOT CHECK SYNTAX ERRORS IN ITS PREPROCESSOR (note to self)

Comment: Yeah. But those errors are easy to miss (if you output anything yourself at all)

Comment: Kitsune: can I see stderr on Visual Studio? would that be in the Output window

Comment: Yes, look in the output window.

Answer (score 1):

I've patched my Qt to use a `qFatal()` instead of `qWarning()`, so the app asserts instead of printing error messages (that cannot be seen when linking against a release-build Qt). YMMV.